# Find all value of $x^2+y^2$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, complex-numbers

$x,  y\in\mathbb{C} $

If $x+y=1$ and $x^{20}+y^{20}=20$

Find all value of $x^2+y^2$

$x=1-y$

$(1-y)^{20} +y^{20} =20$

Vieta's formula,  We get

$y_1+y_2+...+y_{20} =10$

$y_1y_2+...+y_{19} y_{20} =95$, im stuck here

From here we know that 10 pairs (x,  y)  that satisfy.

Comment: Hi, could you please show some effort, so we can see how in which part you are having issues...

Comment: *Maybe* this can help $x=a(\cos u+i \sin u), y=a(\cos u-i \sin u)$ and the De Moivre's  formula.

Comment: @lonestudent we should have $x+y=1$ your equations doesn't seem to satisfy.

Comment: Can you clarify what is $y_1, y_2$? Do you mean $y^1, y^2$?

Comment: @valerin $a \cos u=\frac 12$ and $x^{20}+y^{20}=20$ Moivre formula can help. I am not sure. I don't have a pen and paper with me.  It was the first idea that crossed my mind

Comment: Are you sure that $x, y \in \mathbb{C}$? There are many pairs of solutions to $(1-y)^{20} + y^{20} = 20$, which yield different values for $x^2 + y^2$. I'm guessing that you want $x, y \in \mathbb{R}$ instead, in which case there is a unique answer.

Comment: Sure,  $x, y\in\mathbb{C}$